# Is it possible to generate a sql/csv export without running a mysql server locally?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Essentially I'm hoping to run a python script in jupyter notebook that generates an sql export or a CSV export.

The script currently builds a DB and stores it in a mysql server locally.

Unfortunatly, the machine that generates the data we are building the DB from doesn't have, nor can it have a local mysql server running on it.

Is it possible to 'build the DB' and just hold it in memory and then dump it straight to an export rather than commiting it to a mysql server?

Thanks

Edit:

A little more information for clarity

The script basically takes 5 unrelated excel sheets and produces a relational database from them. I simply use csv to import the data, manipulate it then use mysql.connector to build the structure I want directly into a locally running mysql server.

What I want to do is be able to get a sql export that would allow me skip the step of running a mysql server locally.

The work flow I'm hoping to end up with is:

Load and run script in Jupyter -> SQL export is generated -> move to machine with mysql server and import.

Comment: What do you mean by `a sql export` ? The INSERT commands? CSV is a text file format that doesn't need any kind of database. You could just write the values and commas to a file directly. If you use Pandas you can write a dataframe's contents to a file with `to_csv`.

Comment: What does your code do? Does it use Pandas? What output are you trying to create?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, I will update my question above